# How to import a new codenameone demo-project from github in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, codenameone

im a beginner with codename one. There are many "default" projects when I download codename one. But there are many other projects on github. I took a look on one of the codename one articles. https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-gui-builder-autolayout-signin-form-responsive.html. There it says in one of the first steps you have to download the codenameone-demos repository, then open the Sign In project in Netbeans.

"You’ll need to copy the CodenameOneBuildClient.jar, JavaSE.jar, and lib directory from another Codename One project into the SignIn folder for the dependencies to be met."

Maybe that works with netbeans, but not with eclipse.

Is there an easy way to integrate a new project in eclipse that will be shown in the demo folder when you want to try to make a new codename one project? (New-->Other-->CodenameOne-->Demos->??) Unfortunately i didnt make it to list the new project in the demo folder.

Hope you understand my problem.

Kind regards,

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

See this post: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-setup-codename-one-demo-from-git.html

The TL;DR is:

- Create a new Eclipse project with the same package/main names
- Replace the src directory
- Replace `codenameone_settings.properties`

Comment: Thx for the fast answer. I created a new project, replaced package/main names, src dirc and the properties. But when I run the application I just get the template displayed which is automatically selected some steps before when creating the cn1project.

Comment: You shouldn't change the package/main as those are wired to identify your app to the device. You should create the project with those in the right place to begin with and only make changes to the content of the class not its name or location. I'm not sure I follow what you are seeing. Notice you can edit your question and add a screenshot or just create a new question with a screenshot.